# Происхождение фамилии Паустовский

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Подумалось: а каково происхождение фамилии Паустовский? Вроде, похоже на польскую фамилию...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не обязательно польская, скорее всего как раз чисто русская с полонизирующим суффксом (который, впрочем, встречается и в чисто русских фамилиях). 
Восходит к имени православному имени Фавст или Фауст. Прямого отношения к гетевскому персонажу не имеет, но имя персонажа вполне могло быть того же греческого происхождения, Гете о том, правда, не сообщает.

Отец Константина Георгиевича Паустовского происходил из малороссийских мещан и впоследствии в Киев же с семьёй и вернулся. В тех местах полонизация фамилий была делом вполне обычным, так что есть основания полагать, что история происхождения фамилия писателя та же, что и у большинства его однофамильцев, без прямых польских корней.

Comment: Не лишним будет добавить, что *faust* по-немецки - кулак (легкие гранатометы-фаустпатроны). С латыни *faustus* переводят как удачливый, счастливый, благоприятный, и это вызывает сомнение. Мучеников Фавстов в истории церкви насчитывают на добрую футбольную команду, до того их, счастливых, было много))) Пора вспомнить, что кулак (ладонь) по-старославянски назывался - **пясть**. Известна в истории польская династия Пястов. Пестовать - заботиться, ухаживать.